# how to fix ".... validation failed" using postman with express/bodyParser

Tags: mongodb, express, postman, body-parser

[image]I am making an API using express/bodyparser/MongoDB/postman, but whenever i send a POST request the Schema returns an error, how can i fix this issue?

I've tried different options in Postman, like checking if I had the right options and making sure its set to JSON.

How my requirements look:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const todoRoutes = require("./routes/todos");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

What my Schema looks like:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "Use a string"
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
created_date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
});
```

How my POST request looks:

```
router.post("/",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
db.Todo.create(req.body)
.then(function(newTodo){
  res.json(newTodo);
})
.catch(function(err){
  res.send(err);
});
});
```

The error which is returned by Postman:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "name": {
            "message": "Use a string",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Use a string",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "name"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "name"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Todo validation failed",
    "message": "Todo validation failed: name: Use a string",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

And the console.log of req.body when i give a key of name and a value of GoT :

```
'{\n "name" : "watch GoT"\n}': " }
```

The main odd thing which i see is that for some reason I get a strange log from req.body in the first place ( unusual ' and \n)

Comment: What does your request in Postman look like? What are you sending?

Comment: @DannyDainton i am sending a test entry for my database with key of “name” and value of “Got” . But it isnt accepted by the schema i made giving back “ not a string”

Comment: Can you update the question with an image of what that looks like?

Comment: @DannyDainton  updated it, note that i also did the exact same thing with the same result using the <body> tab

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the body tab in Postman and select xxx-w-form-urlencoded

[image: this should clear it up]

Answer (score 0):

To post a URL parameter's value, use req.params

```
   router.post("/",function(req,res){

   db.Todo.create({ name = req.params.name })
   .then(function(newTodo){
    res.json(newTodo);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
    res.send(err);
    });
     });
```